# How to input a variable which contains multiple simultaneous options

Tags: r, variables

I am analyzing a data set which is feedback from teachers. Each line in the data frame is a teacher, each of their answers is a variable, however I've run into a problem inputting the year level for each teacher as a lot of the teachers teach multiple grades.

eg:

```
Teacher  Year
a         1
b         3
c         1/2
d         7
e         3/4
```

How can I enter this data into an excel sheet and then into R and analyse it usefully? I've never dealt with a variable before which contains multiple options on the same row.

Comment: Do you need help with entering/reading data in R from excel ?

Comment: Could you provide the sample year levels that you want to assign to each teacher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you already have this data in R in an object called `teacher_data`. I will show you the way to deal with such responses that I have seen most commonly employed: you create additional columns so that each answer gets its own cell via the convenient [`tidyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/index.html) function `separate()`.

```
library(tidyr)
separate(teacher_data, col = "Year", into = paste0("Year", 1:2), sep = "/")
```

Here's the result:

```
  Teacher Year1 Year2
1       a     1  <NA>
2       b     3  <NA>
3       c     1     2
4       d     7  <NA>
5       e     3     4
```

How you then use those columns kind of depends on what sort of answer you're trying to ask with the data. This part of your question is probably best asked at the sister site [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) (Stack Exchange for statistics).

As far as Excel goes, I would not even deal with Excel as an intermediate step; it's just unnecessary. If you write the data out when you're done into a CSV, Excel can read CSVs just fine:

```
write.csv(teacher_data, file = "teacher_data.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Also, just so you know, I put your data into R via the following:

```
teacher_data <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
Teacher  Year
a         1
b         3
c         1/2
d         7
e         3/4")
```

Comment: Thank you for this! How would I use the data in this format to plot it on a simple graph though as Year1 and Year2 are now separate variables. I gave it a go with ggplot2 but I can only seem to get one or the other in a graph, not both at the same time, and if I plot Year2 it adds all the NA's in. Here's what I tried with the DF you created using my data.
`library(tidyr)
teacher_data1 <- separate(teacher_data, col = "Year", into = paste0("Year", 1:2), sep = "/")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = teacher_data1, mapping = aes(y = Year1, x = Teacher)) +
  geom_point()`